# How to get route name in handler using react-route?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

As on subject how can I get the route name inside the handler?
For example:

```js
var routes = <Route handler={App} path="/">
    <Route name="home" path="/home" handler={HomePage} />
    <DefaultRoute handler={HomePage} />
</Route>

Router.run(routes, function(Handler, state) {
  var params = state.params;
  React.render(<Handler params={params}/>, document.body);
});
```

Now suppose I have a component like this:

```js
class HomePage extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(<div>MyComponent</div>)
    }
}
```

how can I get the current route name? To be more specific I want to get the

```js
name="home"
```

attribute from

```js
<Route name="home" path="/home" handler={HomePage} />
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Before react-router 0.13 you can use `this.getRoutes()` using `Router.State` mixin.

For react-router 0.13 you can use this too:

```js
var currentRoutes = this.context.router.getCurrentRoutes();
var lastRoute = currentRoutes[currentRoutes.length - 1];
console.log(lastRoute.name);
```

For react-router v2.0.x you can use:

```js
this.props.routes[this.props.routes.length-1]
```

Comment: Thanks, removed the link to avoid confusion.

Comment: As of v2.0.x, it looks like this approach no longer works - getCurrentRoutes has been removed from the router.  I used ```this.props.routes[this.props.routes.length-1]``` which appears to have similar behavior

Comment: It might be `this.props.routes[0].path` now

Answer (score 5):

## react-router 4

v4 has removed the JS API from the code base which means the above methods won't work moving forward.

The new way is to actually pass the props directly to the component being rendered, just like you normally would with any other component in you React app.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Match, Link, Miss } from 'react-router';
import DocumentMeta from 'react-document-meta';

import MainLayout from './Layouts/MainLayout';
import Homepage from './containers/Homepage/Homepage';
import Game from './containers/Game/Game';
import NotFound from './containers/NotFound/NotFound';

export const routes = {
  homepage: {
    exactly: true,
    pattern: '/',
    label: 'About React Lego',
    component: Homepage
  },
  game: {
    pattern: '/game',
    label: 'Star Wars Trivia',
    component: Game
  }
};

const passPropsToRoute = ({ route, props }) => (
  <span>
    <DocumentMeta title={ route.title } />
    <route.component {...props} routes={route.routes}/>
  </span>
);

const matchWithSubRoutes = (key, i) => {
  const route = routes[key];
  return (<Match { ...route } key={ i } render={(props) => passPropsToRoute({ route, props })} />);
};

export function makeRoutes() {
  return (
    <MainLayout>
      {Object.keys(routes).map(matchWithSubRoutes)}
      <Miss title={`${siteTitle} - Page Not Found`} component={ NotFound } />
    </MainLayout>
  );
}
```

To see this working in a example app, take a look at [react-lego](https://github.com/peter-mouland/react-lego) which has a [react-router-4 branch](https://github.com/peter-mouland/react-lego/blob/react-router-4/src/app/routes.js)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we are talking about the same react-router (and the current version is 2.8.x) you can access the route directly via `this.props.route.path`, which will be `/home` for your home page (in `HomePage` component).

Link to the [docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v2.8.1/docs/API.md#route).

Edit: link updated.

Comment: That link should now be: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v2.8.1/docs/API.md#route